# how to get discrete values as output in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to get an output just like [3,4,0,2,1] (discrete values between 0 and 4) without repetition.
this is the code of my model:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(5,5))
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(500, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(ordre)(output1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[output1])
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"],optimizer="adam")
```

ordre function is implemented :

```
def ordre(tensor):
  return tf.argsort(tensor,direction='DESCENDING')
```

but I get as error

```
TypeError: Expected int32, but got 1e-07 of type 'float'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your output tensor is, just round.

```
output = tf.math.round(output)
```